# Audio total duration is showing NaN in Ipad by using Jplayer

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, audio, jplayer

I am using Jplayer to play audio, In my application i have some audio files loading once page changes, but some time it show me total duration NaN and also progress bar will not show.

I used this code to change audio

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "audio/newFile.mp3"
     }).jPlayer("play");
```

When i change audio file, it some times display duration but some time it does not display audio duration and also not display progress bar.

Please help me.
Thanks.